# fancybox2 ie 10, iframe not disappear

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, internet-explorer-10, fancybox-2

When I hide the fancybox with iframe in ie 10, the fancybox disappear and the iframe stucks.
Fancybox version: 2.1.4.
My html:

```
<ul class="gallery_new">
    <li id="104" class="video">
        <span>title</span>
        <a href="images/gallerys/kids/big/wipeout2.jpg" class="fancybox">
            <img src="images/g2allerys/kids/thumbnails/wipeout2_thumb.jpg">
        </a>
        <a class="showVideo" href="#video104"></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div style="display:none" id="video104">
    <iframe width="425" height="355" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bYS2hrj9HzI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

And the js is:

```
$("ul.gallery_new > li > a.fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',

        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            }
        }
    });

  $("ul.gallery_new > li > a.showVideo").fancybox();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is not a good idea to have inline `iframes` unless is strictly necessary but in your case I don't think so.

You could remove your hidden inline container `id="video104"` and modify your html to link the youtube video directly like :

```
<a id="video104" class="showVideo" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bYS2hrj9HzI">show video</a>
```

then use this script :

```
$("a.showVideo").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    width: 425,
    height: 355,
    fitToView: false
});
```

Doing this, your video will be called only when it's need it. This also will help to improve your page load.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m37SR/)**

**NOTE**: you can enable the video's autoplay mode by adding `?autoplay=1` as a trailing parameter within the URL like :

```
<a id="video104" class="showVideo" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bYS2hrj9HzI?autoplay=1">show video</a>
```